# A combinatorial 0-1 matrix problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices

Let $M \in \{0, 1\}^{n\times n}$.
Given a constant integer $c \ge 2$, let the number of $1$s in each row be equal to $n/c$ (assuming $c$ is a divisor of $n$).

Given a constant $\beta \in (0,1)$, we call a row vector $r\,$
"$z$-*orthogonal*" if the number of $M$'s row vectors $r'$ such that $\,r' r^{\top} \le z\,n\,$ is greater or equal to $n-n^{\beta}$.

Question: When $n$ approaches infinity, what is the maximum number $N$ 
of $z$-orthogonal row vectors of $M$, in the case $z$ is strictly smaller than $1/c^2$?

---

---

Note: If $z \ge 1/c^2$ is very easy to show how to construct $M$ such that $N=n$.

In the case $z < 1/c^2$, it seems to me that $N=(c-1)n^{\beta}$, but I am not completely sure and I do not know how to prove it.

### ---

**Update**: I just posted now the "real" (complete) question from which this (sub)problem arose: [Combinatorial 0-1 vector problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288111/combinatorial-0-1-vector-problem).

Comment: Relation of this to your earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287695/0-1-matrix-combinatorial-problem ?

Comment: What's wrong with putting all ones to the left half for $n/2$ rows and to the right half for the remaining $n/2$ rows achieving $z=0$ and $N=n$ (if you agree to consider $n/2$ as $\omega(1)$? What you, probably, really wanted to ask was the question if we can find many sets $E_j$ on $[0,1]$ of measure $1/c$ with $|E_k\cap E_m|\le a<c^{-2}$ for $k\ne m$. Then, indeed, there is a bound $C(a,c)$ for the size of any such family (just apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the sum of the characteristic functions of $E_j$).

Comment: Gerry, the relation of this to my earlier question is a bit complicated. Basically I trying to simplify the "real" question underlying https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287695/0-1-matrix-combinatorial-problem. When I will understand how to proceed in order to solve the problem I am addressing, I will delete the meaningless questions.

Comment: @fedja, thank you! I made a mistake in the problem definition. Instead of "equal to $\omega(1)$" I should have written "greater or equal to $n-n^{\beta}$ for a given constant $\beta \in (0,1)$". 

The answer seems to me $N=(c-1)n^{\beta}$, but I am not completely sure and I do not know how to prove it. Do you think it is correct? Thank you again!

PS: I just edited the text of my question.

Comment: It is, indeed $C(z,c)n^\beta$ now and, if you bothered to follow the hint and solve the little puzzle I told you, you should certainly know how to get such bound by now (if the number of $z$-orthogonal vectors is too large compared to $n^\beta$, then you can use the greedy algorithm to choose more than $C(z,c)$ pairwise $z$-orthogonal vectors and that is impossible). However $c-1$ is certainly too optimistic for the constant. It should depend on $z$ too and blow up as $z\to c^{-2}$. Really, think of that old teaser for students a bit and you'll know everything one can know here :-)

Comment: If there are answers posted to your "meaningless questions", Penelope, I hope you *won't* delete them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson of course, if there are answer I will not delete them. Thanks.

Comment: @fedja thank you very much for your advice!
I am sorry, there is something that is still not clear to me. About the old teaser for students you mentioned before: If I see each set $E_j$ as a $0-1$-vector having $n$ elements ($n/c$ 1s and $n-n/c$ 0s), applying Cauchy-Schwarz to the sum of the characteristic functions of the sets $E_j$, I get $\sum_{k\neq m}|E_k \cap E_m| \ge N^2 \frac{n}{c^2}$, where $N$ is the number of sets $E_j$. However, I do not know to use this fact for proving that,
when $|E_k \cap E_m| \le an < c^{-2}n$ for all $k \neq m$, $N$ does *not* depend on $n$.

Comment: Using Cauchy-Schwarz it seems that for $a \ge c^{-2}$ we obtain as expected $N=n$, while for $a < c^{-2}$, $N$ *abruptly* decreases to a constant depending on $c$ and $a$. Anyway I just posted now the "real" complete question
from which this (sub)problem arose, because I am realising now it is better to provide the complete problem in order to show what I *really* would like to understand (here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288111/combinatorial-0-1-vector-problem)

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati You were almost there. Just two things: You should have got $\sum_{k\ne m}|E_k\cap E_m|\ge N^2 \frac n{c^2}-\frac Nc$ (the scalar products of sets with themselves count, don't they?). And, of course, you should use your condition that each intersection is at most $zn$, so the LHS is not greater than $zN(N-1)$, which has a smaller coefficient at $N^2$ than the RHS if $z<c^{-2}$, so the linear term can hold the inequality valid only for constant time.

Comment: @fedja, yes, of course, thank you a lot! :-)

Comment: [ PS: I am sorry, I accidentally undone my upvote on your comment and I see now I cannot upvote it again according to these system rules... : - / ]